# Android FFmpeg: get frame count from video

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I only want to filter out 20% of frames from the start of the video and the end of the video, but i cant do that if i dont have total frame count.

I alr know how to filter out frames, i just need to know how to get total frame count of a video.

I've looked this up, and there was answers saying use ffprobe to fetch total number of frames in a video. However ffmpeg for android doesnt have it.. is there another way to get the frame count from a video?

Compiled ffmpeg for android using:

> compile 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'

Comment: Do you have grep available?

Comment: I don't think so, is that the only way to do frame count? Is the method tedious? I'm kinda dumb so i need a pretty detailed tutorial to get stuff done haha :x

Comment: Running `ffmpeg -i video -c copy -f null -` will show at the end the frame count. With grep, that value could have been isolated.